# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body content: Must be 4000 or fewer in length

Tags: javascript, discord.js

I'm making a discord bot that snipes edit, but it always shows

> UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body content: Must be 4000 or fewer in length."

but it the text never got up to 4000 characters in the first place

```
const { MessageEmbed, Discord } = require("discord.js")

module.exports.run = async(client, message, args, Discord) => {

  const esnipes = client.esnipes.get(message.channel.id)
  if(!esnipes) return message.reply({ content: 'There is nothin to snipe :|'})

  const esnipe = +args[0] - 1 || 0
  const target = esnipes[esnipe]
  if (!target) {
    message.reply(`There are ${snipes.length} to snipes.`)
  }
  const { newc, msg } = target
      new MessageEmbed() 
      .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
      .addField('old Message', msg.content)
      .addField('New Content', newc.content)

      message.channel.send(MessageEmbed)
}

exports.conf = {
    enabled: true,
    guildOnly: true,
    aliase:["es"]
}

exports.help = {
    name:"editsnipe",
    description:"Empty",
    usage:"esnipes",
    category:"general"
}
```

Comment: Did you tried console logging messages' contents?

Comment: @MegaMix_Craft no i havent, how do i do that (sorry i sound like an idiot)

Comment: oh ok lemme try that

Comment: still doesn't work,  but i see the old message and new message in the console

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here

```js
message.channel.send(MessageEmbed)
```

`MessageEmbed` is a class. You may have wanted to use the one below

```js
let embed = new MessageEmbed() 
      .setAuthor(msg.author.tag, msg.author.displayAvatarURL({dynamic: true}))
      .addField('old Message', msg.content)
      .addField('New Content', newc.content)
message.channel.send({ embeds: [embed] })
//on v12 you can just use message.channel.send(embed)
```

Comment: its now showing "UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Cannot send an empty message"

Comment: Embeds need a title and description. Use `.setTitle()` and `.setDescription()` on the embed

Comment: still doesn't work D:

Comment: What exactly are you doing?

Comment: https://pastebin.com/mRd0Zvn4

That's the new code, im making a editsnipe bot :|

Comment: In v12 it's only `message.channel.send(embed)` or `message.channel.send({ embed })` I think

Comment: AH STUPID ME, my discord.js is v12, thanks dude :D